# Showing RecyclerView ItemAnimation for child RecyclerView inside parent RecyclerView

Tags: android-layout, android-animation, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have below layout structure for homepage of one of my apps-

```
<RelativeLayout>
<Toolbar>
<RecyclerView>
<!-- This recycler view has 4 itemView types-->
</RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that the recyclerview above has 4 custom itemViews 
`1.ViewPager` `2.RecyclerView (Grid with 8 items and 3x3 structure)` `3.RecyclerView (Grid 4 columns.)` and `4.RecyclerView (List view mode.)`
Now I want to show animation like flip for the child `recyclerview's` items. I already have animation code and it works fine when items are first laid out. But animation works only once. I want it to work every time when I scroll my Parent `recyclerview`. Is there a way to do so. Currently animation is added in `onBinViewHolder()` method of child `recyclerView1`. So it gets called only once and hence animation is shown only once.
Below is the link to gif-
  [Please check that card flip effect appears only when recyclerview items are laid out first time.](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/AffectionateDisfiguredFlamingo)

Comment: can you link of image/gif about the current behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: I will try to add it after sometime..

Comment: @AkshayShinde added the Gif...please check.